# Reply All to emails using python Imap4

Tags: python, imap

I have a working code that replies to email from a specific inbox.

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['In-Reply-To'] = orig_mail['message_id']
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient
msg['Subject'] = subject
```

I need to **Reply All** to that email instead of just **Reply** .
Is there any way i can implement that here? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think **Reply ALL** feature is there. But this would work out if you want to send mail to multiple people

```
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
msg['From'] = sender
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
```